# How to get text field value from another page javascript

Tags: javascript

Here My script code

page 1 / index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#list").load("load_list.php");
  function reloadlist(){
     var total_list = $("#total").val();
     $.get('load_list.php', function(data){
        var values = $("input[name='total']", data).val();
        alert(values);
     });
  } setInterval(reloadlist, 3000);
})

<body>
  <div id="list"></div>
</body>
```

page 2 / load_list.php

```
[My query for get the total data]

<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="<?=$total?>">
```

When i load that index page, and alert value will be undefined. how to get text field value from load_list.php

Answer (score 1):

save the value in a cookie and retrive it in next page

Answer (score 0):

The element is at root level, and the contex selector uses `find()` internally, and that only works on descendants.

You can avoid any and all issues with elements being descendants or at root level by appending the content to another element, and then using `find()`, or you could use `filter()` directly

```
 $.get('load_list.php', function(data){
    var values =  $('<div />', {html: data}).find("input[name='total']").val();
    alert(values);
 });
```

Also, the element has an ID, and it would be more efficient to use that in the selector.

Comment: It's still undefined . . .

Answer (score 0):

You're in kind of a bad situation since you're just reloading the list after 3 seconds even if the call failed. You should try to clean up the whole idea a bit.

```
function reloadList = setTimeout(function(){
  $.get('load_list.php', function(result){
    var value = $(data).filter('#total').val();
    alert(value);
    reloadList();
  });
}, 3000);

reloadList();
```